# When is $\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{e^{X^T \beta}}{1 + e^{X^T \beta}} XX^T\right]$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Let $X$ be a $d$-dimensional random vector, and $\beta$ a vector. When is the following matrix positive definite?

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{e^{X^T \beta}}{1 + e^{X^T \beta}} XX^T\right]$$

My notes says it is positive definite if $\mathbb{E}\left[XX^T\right]$ is non-singular, but I don't see why is that? My notes could be wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

Take care that exponential term is only a positive value.but the whole can never be a positive definite matrix. rank of multiplication of two matrix $A$ , $B$ follows this relation:
$$rank(AB) \le min (rank(A),rank(B))$$
So rank of the term $XX^T$  can not be more than 1 and it has $d-1$ zero eigenvalue. It is only a positive semidefinite matrix and alway it is singular.

Comment: I don't get it. why the rank of $XX^T$ cannot be more than $1$?

Comment: Rank of a vector is always equal to 1. Of course it should not be zero.Rank of a matrix is defined according to linear dependence between its rows and columns as vectors. set $A=X$ and $B=X^T$ and conclude

Comment: $XX^T$ is a matrix. $X$ is a column vector.

Comment: I dont know what you are argueing about.A vector also is a matrix. if it is hard to understand. Consider  vector $X=[1\ 2\ 3]^T$ and calculate the eigenvalues  of $XX^T$. Be sure that it has two(3-1) zero eigenvalues.